# cakephp/ cakedc routes and urls

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I'm using CakePHP3 with CakeDC, and setup my routes like this:

```
/* config/routes.php */
Router::prefix('Customers', function($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/',  ['controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

/* vendor/cakedc/users/config/routes.php */
Router::plugin('CakeDC/Users', ['path' => '/customers'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/users/:action', ['controller' => 'Users'], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);
    $routes->connect('/users/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Users'], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

The routes are both loaded.

Basically all URLs have the prefix `Customers`, like `www.url.com/customers/dashboard`

With this routes I can access the profile by going to `www.url.com/customers/users/profile`. Which is working fine.

In my default layout I want to create a link to the page, so I've used:

```
$this->Html->link('Profile', ['plugin'=>'CakeDC/Users', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action'=>'Profile']);
```

Which leads to this error:

> Error: A route matching "array ( 'plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users',
>   'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'Profile', '_ext' => NULL, )"
>   could not be found.

I've tried adding the `customer` prefix, but still the error exists.

What am I overseeing here?

Comment: Don't know that it'll fix your problem, but I think you want your action in lower case, `profile` not `Profile`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, thanks for the suggestion, didn't work tho...

Comment: in your config/bootstrap.php file where you add a plugin, did you set routes equals to true for this particular route?. I guess you are missing that only. something like this. Plugin::load('PluginName', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);